# How to change server Elasticsearch version?

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

I have Magento CE 2.4.6 running on a Ubuntu server with Elasticsearch 8.11.4. For a mandatory module I absolutely need, I need to downgrade to ES 7.9.3.

I read everywhere it was not possible to downgrade ES. Is there a way to uninstall ES 8.4.11 and install ES 7.9.3 without damaging the system? If yes, how?

(I don't want to make any mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade from 7.x to 8.x creates changes in indices and configurations that are not easy  revesible.
Suggestion: build a test 7.x cluster and add the snapshot repositroy from 8.x as READ-ONLY. Import your indices one by one and test to see if you can still use them or what changes are necessary so you can revert them to 7.x . Once you tested all of them and you know it is doable, make a prod cluster and migrate all closed indices . Then test your integrations and plan a rupture day. You can migrate services one by one to minimize data loss or make a planed downtime .
You also need to read all the [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/breaking-changes-7.8.html) inbetween your versions